# Calling designer-built event handlers

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently tasked with cleaning up, bug fixing and optimising a Form in winforms (3000 lines of code in one `.cs` file, it's getting a bit ugly!). I've noticed a few obvious bad practices and some redundant calls already which I could sort out relatively easily.

However there's one that is popping up a lot which seems to me like bad practice, but I can't actually back it up with any documentation. I could be completely wrong.

```
private void datePicker_DateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  tabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
}

private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  tabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
}
```

My first concern is that the method will have the `sender` object that is the date picker or the combo box, but does this matter? I asked myself, what is the sender object there for? Perhaps this is why it's there? I also find `EventArgs` by itself is pretty useless as far (as I'm aware) unless the class is inherited.

I know that neither the `sender` or `EventArgs` are used in the `tabControl_SelectedIndexChanged` method, so the code works fine. What about possible future implications when some code is changed?

Should I change these to 3 different event handlers that all point to a simple `void loadCurrentTab()` method? Or perhaps I should get all 3 controls to call the same event handler, such as `loadCurrentTab(sender, e)`? Or just leave it as it is? Is it that important?

Comment: Do you really want to add more code?  I seriously doubt this code is broken.

Comment: Please re-read the first 6 words of the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I change these to 3 different event handlers that all point to a simple void loadCurrentTab() method?

This would actually be my preference, in this scenario.  This makes the intent very clear - all three event handlers are routing to one set of logic which (by design) doesn't pay attention to the sender or `EventArgs`.

Answer (score 2):

My biggest issue with calling event handlers (aside from it being poor practice) is when you are looking at call stacks with a quick glance, in your case, you would see that the selected index of the tab changes when that did not actually happen.

It's also a good practice to not have unused parameters in your method calls.  There are a handful of exceptions (event handling for one) but for any code that *I* write, I try to be sure I always use what I'm providing.

Answer (score 2):

To start with, it's not all that important. Consider not fixing what isn't broken.

The preferred approach would be to have several handlers all calling a special method (not an eventhandler).

```
private void datePicker_DateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // tabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
   RefreshCurrentTabControl();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

calling other EventHandler is obviously not good pracice. Becouse if   `tabControl_SelectedIndexChanged` change in time and start depend on sender all code fails or star work unexpedted..

I'll separate same logic in third method like you said.. `loadCurrentTab()`. You also may consider use some command pattern to handle events -> good way to separate Business Logic from GUI.

For example:

```
interface ICommand {
    void Execute();
}

interface IEventCommand : ICommand {
    void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e); 
}


class CommandAttribute : Attribute {
     ...
}

class MyCommand : IEventCommand {
     ...
}
```

implement some manager, executor, attach command using reflection, etc...

And then you can attach command like this:

```
[Command(typeof(MyCommand), new [] {"Click"})]
private Button m_oButton = new Button();
```

All nessesary parameters are auto-magically ;) passed to command.

Comment: Yup I thought of this. If I went with the solution in Reeds answer, any future developers would've even have the option to start using the `sender`, which is a good thing, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Yep that's bad practice, you twiddle with one and break the other in ignorance, classic error would be as simple as ((ComboBox)sender).SomeProperty, because "it can only be called from the Combobox".

Depends on how far you can afford to take the refactoring, but my instant reaction would be at least "RefreshTabControl" to do the work and then get the eventHandlers to call it. If you have to expand upon that, ie Sender Or EventArgs matters, then some form of delegation as suggested, or not as clever but much better than what you have, would be an overload.

e.g
void RefreshTabControl(Combobox argBox, EventArgs e)
and then a cast and null check in the eventhandler, at least that would be a statement of intent.

What you have now is a bug waiting to happen.